# Insert /r/n on pressing enter in contenteditable

Tags: php, html, editor, contenteditable

I am creating a simple code editor. After writing the code in a contenteditable `<div>`, I use `.textContent` to get its value and save it to a file. Now, the problem is that whenever I press enter in a contenteditable div, its `textContent` adds a `"\n"`. However, I need it to add a `"\r\n"` on pressing enter. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hmm.... no replies yet.

Comment: you can replace \n with \r\n from the string after you get textContent

Comment: @ITgoldman, but what if the I write a "\n" in the code editor? It would replace that also.

Answer (score 0):

You will write `\n` as text but it's not the same as `\n` the char that is added automatically. So all in all, search and replace will work.

```js
function save() {
  var div = document.querySelector("#div");
  var text = div.innerText;
  console.log (JSON.stringify(text))
  text = text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');
  console.log (JSON.stringify(text))
}
```

```html
<div id="div" contenteditable style="border: 1px solid black; padding:20px">edit me</div>
<button onclick="save()">save</button>
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but there is one major flaw in this: the returned text often seems to have extra /r/n s.  For eg, try writing something with with a few newlines in between and save it. Then try setting the value of the div using the returned JSON. They won't match.

Comment: the JSON.stringify is just for the demonstration you don't need to stringify the result

Comment: I am talking about the result u receive from the save() function. Try with that what I said and you will see.

Comment: There are some issues because it is not `\n` that is being added but rather a `<br>` or `<div><br></div>` sometimes.  So when you convert that to `innerText` it isn't exact.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem I am talking about. Anyways, thanks for trying to help.